# Physics notation

Tags: math-mode, accents

[image]

I really don't know how to write that 'Y' in latex. I have tried many methods but I didn't succeed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I changed the tag as this clearly isn't related to `biblatex`. Are you talking about the Y, or the Y with the underline?

Comment: Y with the underline

Comment: `\underline{Y}`

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want the underline to extend that far over the symbols' “boundaries”, you might want to consider using the `accents` package for the macro `\underaccent{<accent>}{<glyph>}`.  See the following MWE for an illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\underaccent{\bar}{Y}$ vs.\ $\underline{Y}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would start with

```
\underline{Y}
```

in either inline-math or displaystyle-math mode.